# NotifyOfPropertyChange Not updating in realtime

Tags: wpf, .net-6.0, caliburn.micro

I have two Textboxes, I tried to update the second Textbox when i changed the first one but it's only work when i clicked another control or we can say a Button and also if i change the Second Textbox and click the button the First Textbox not gonna be updated.

I'm using WPF .Net 6.0

> ShellView

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.Views.ShellView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="ShellView" Height="450" Width="450">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name , Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Name" />
        
        <Button Content="Click Me" />
        
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

> ShellViewModel

```
public class ShellViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    string name = "";

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Name);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Recorded GIF]

Comment: Default behaviour of the textbox text binding is to transfer the value to your viewmodel when the textbox loses focus. You can change that if you particularly wanted. https://wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/the-update-source-trigger-property/#:~:text=Summary,updated%20UI%20and%20good%20performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To synchronize both `TextBox` elements you must bind them to a common property using `BindingMode.TwoWay` (if both elements can update each other).

To update the `Binding` set on the `TextBox.Text` property without moving the focus, you must configure the `Binding` accordingly by setting `Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger` to `UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged`. The default value is `UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged`. But `TextBox` internally changes this default to `UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus` to improve the performance and input handling for common scenarios. `TextBox` also sets the `Binding.Mode` of the `TextBox.Text` property to `BindingMode.TwoWay` which otherwise would default to `BindingMode.OneWay`.

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<TextBox x:Name="Name" 
         Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

If you e.g. trigger the operation that processes the text field's input with a button, I recommend to leave the `UpdateSourceTrigger` at the default.

[Microsoft Docs: Data binding overview (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0)